# java configuration file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a method :

```
private String getProperty(String property) throws IOException,ConfigException {

    // first test if the config file exists.
    String propertyFile = "DataTransfer/Config/DataTransfer.properties";

    if(!new File(propertyFile).exists()) {
        throw new ConfigException("the config file doesn't exist." +
            " Make sure the file : \""+propertyFile+"\" exists.");
    }   

    // retrieve the property
    Properties configFile = new Properties();

    configFile.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream(propertyFile));

    String prop = configFile.getProperty(property);
    return prop;
}
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` at the `ConfigFile.load()` level.

I checked my variables in debug mode, none of them is null.

I don't know what's the cause for this exception.

Comment: As an aside, you try to load the properties file for every property you get. Loading it once and reusing the properties collection seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
configFile.load(new FileReader(new File(propertyFile)));
```

to check and load in same style

Answer (score 5):

You've checked that it exists as a file in the current working directory. You haven't checked that it exists on the classpath.

If you know it exists as a file, why not load it as a file?

If you want to load it from the classpath, why not change the check to make sure it exists on the classpath?

Basically you need to be consistent between your checking and your loading.

Comment: ok, thx. how would I load it as a file ? don't know how to use InputStream.

Comment: configFile.load(new FileInputStream("DataTransfer/Config/DataTransfer.properties"));

Comment: @Attilah: With the greatest of respect, if you don't know how to use `InputStream` you shouldn't be trying to write a J2EE application. Learn the core parts of Java first, and *then* move on to more complicated topics like J2EE.

Answer (score 1):

[ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream(String)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) returns `null` if the resource cannot be found by the ClassLoader hierarchy. This will most likely be the root cause.

Classloading, especially in J2EE-Environments, is often misunterstood.

Comment: Common issue? It's just a matter of understanding how it works.

Comment: @BalusC indeed, but it's a commonly misunderstood mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I refer you to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883858/what-is-the-best-practice-for-reading-property-files-in-j2ee) regarding best practices for reading configuration files in J2EE environments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this 
FileInputStream infile = new FileInputStream(new File(libjavaFolder+"log4j.properties"));
        if(infile != null) {
            Properties logProps = new Properties();
            logProps.load(infile);
            infile.close();
                      }

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the configfile is in that particular folder and that you're actually looking in the right path. I usually add something like this before the load method:

```
System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".").getFile());
```

This will print the absloute path